# Where-clause for LINQ-to-NHibernate FetchMany?

Tags: linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

Using LINQ-to-NHibernate is there a way to narrow down what `FetchMany()` returns?

Given the following class structure

```cs
public class Foo
{
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual IList<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}
public class Bar
{
  public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}
```

How can I do this:

```cs
session.Query<Foo>()
  .Where(foo => foo.Id > 30)
  .FetchMany(foo => 
    foo.Bars.Where(bar => bar.Description.StartsWith("x")));
```

And NHibernate will return all Foo's with an Id > 30 and for those Foo's all the attached Bar's where the Bar's description starts with the letter 'x'?

I found some posts that use the old `QueryOver()` stuff but I explicitely want to use NHibernate's LINQ provider.

Any ideas?

---

**Update**

I think I need to clarify what I want as a result.

```xml
<Foo Id="1">
  <Bar Description="x1"/>
  <Bar Description="b1"/>
</Foo>
<Foo Id="31">
  <Bar Description="x2"/>
  <Bar Description="x3"/>
  <Bar Description="b2"/>
</Foo>
<Foo Id="32">
  <Bar Description="b3"/>
</Foo>
```

From the data outlined above I expect the following result

```xml
<Foo Id="31">
  <Bar Description="x2"/>
  <Bar Description="x3"/>
</Foo>
<Foo Id="32"/>
```

The additional Where clause should only work on the Bar's! It should not further narrow down the list of Foo's! Just reduce what `FetchMany()` returns.

Comment: What does it return now?

Comment: @GertArnold Right now that query won't even compile... If I remove the second Where-clause it will return all Foo's with an Id > 30 plus ALL Bars attached to each one of them. I can't find a way to do any filtering on what the call to 'FetchMany()' will return.

Comment: @SebastianWeber Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @SarabjeetSingh sorry I can't really remember. The idea with the filters DanP mentioned sounds vaguely familiar but I'm not sure if we really used that one.

Comment: @SebastianWeber I just tried the filters option as suggested by DanP and it is working as per my expectations. Thank you.

Comment: @SarabjeetSingh Just stumbled across the [release notes for EFCore 5.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#filtered-include) where they added support for just that feature

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure you're out of luck with the current linq provider - but for a non-linq (and cross-cutting) option, you might want to have a look at the [filter](http://ayende.com/blog/3993/nhibernate-filters) functionality included in NHibernate - it would probably be the best bet for implementing this in a large scale / complex project.

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = from foo in session.Query<Foo>()
            where foo.Id >30
            from bar in foo.Bars
            where bar.Description.StartsWith("x")
            select new { Id = foo, Bar = bar};
var results = query.ToList().ToLookup(x => x, x => x.Bar);
foreach(var foo in results.Keys)
{
   var barsWhichStartWithX = results[foo];
   //DO STUFF
}
```

Although this may produce inefficient SQL (I don't use nHibernate so I wouldn't know). You could also try this...Also the above would miss out foos without bars.

```
var foosQuery = session.Query<Foo>().Where(foo => foo.Id > 30);
var foos = foosQuery.Future();
var barsQuery = from f in foosQuery
                from bar in foo.Bars
                select new { Id = foo.Id, Bar = bar};
var foosDict = foos.ToDictionary(x => x.Id);
var bars = barsQuery.ToList().ToLookup(x => foosDict[x.Id], x => x.Bar);
foreach(var foo in foos)
{
   var barsWhichStartWithX = bars[foo];
   //DO STUFF
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not *exactly* what you're after, but certainly worth considering is the [NHibernate.CollectionQuery](http://nuget.org/packages/NHibernate.CollectionQuery) library.

It allows you to query uninitialized NHibernate collections on an entity using Linq - but would require an additional query/round-trip to get them (unlike FetchMany, which grabs the entire collection in the same round-trip).

Comment: It will produce SELECT N+1 problem.

Comment: We have a rather complex object hierarchy. Manually querying every collection would add too much overhead (both in code and in number of round-trips). But it looks like an interesting project.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a reference from child object to the parent.

```
var result = from foo in session.Query<Foo>().FetchMany(f => f.Bars)
             from bar in session.Query<Bar>()
             where foo.Id == bar.FooId && // FooId is missing in your entity
                   foo.Id > 30
                   bar.Description.StartsWith("x")
             select foo;
```

Comment: There is no "back-link" from Bar to Foo in our model and we don't plan to introduce one just for the purpose of these queries.